# Provides methods must return a value (not void)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

When I try to use Dagger 2 it gives this error, what should I do, I'm in Dagger 2 new

```
e: /Users/stepanbezhuk/Documents/Work/Rebus/Movie/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/popularmovies/movies/Service/MessageWorking.java:11: error: @Provides methods must return a value (not void)
    public final void messageConnected$app_debug(boolean networkStatus) {
```

Module 1

```
 @Module
 open class MessageWorking @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {

 @Provides
 internal fun messageConnected(networkStatus: Boolean) {
      if (networkStatus) {
          showMessage(message = "Connect")
      } else {
          showMessage(message = "Disconnect")
      }
  }

  private fun showMessage(message: String) {
      return Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
}
```

Interface

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(MessageWorking::class))

@Singleton
interface DaggerComponent {
    fun messageConnected(networkStatus: Boolean)
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do? I think you does't know Dagger2's concepts and why we are using Dagger2.
Dagger2 uses providers to create instances of required objects. so it must return a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `@Provides` annotations mean you must provide something back. you have no return type in `messageConnected()`.

You are doing UI stuff inside Dagger (toast), which is very odd since the dagger's responsibility is to provide dependencies.

Here is a link to a simple intro to Dagger and how to setup:
https://medium.com/@skshayne/understanding-dagger-as-a-beginner-8ffe29bad429